# How do I know if Applebot started indexing my site?

Tags: ios, spotlight, ios-searchapi, applebot

We've implemented everything apple requires for making our site's content available in Spotlight and Safari search results:

- web markup
- universal links
- entitlements + associations

But the site still won't appear in spotlight or safari search.

Is there a way to track if Applebot started indexing the site, or what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your robots.txt allows for the applebot and it does not block subdirectories

```
User-agent: Applebot
Disallow: /private/
```